# Djangos manage.py makemessages somehow translates all folders in / but not in project dir

Tags: python, django, translation

Instead of using

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/home/myuser/www/django/myproject/locale/'
)
```

manage.py translates all folders in /, like mnt, proc, etc

I remember adding -l en_EN etc when using django-admin outside of folder, so Django remembered those things and maybe now translates everything outside, because there are these entries (that included I assume every folder in /, when I was playing with django-admin outside project folrt) in some sort of django cache.
Can I somehow remove them from this 'cache'?

Comment: You are missing comma after the string. `LOCALE_PATHS` is supposed to be a tuple.

Comment: dhke, please submit this as answer so it can be accept.